# laser_frame is moving

Tags: amcl, ros-humble, differential-drive

When I launch AMCL and give initial pose , the amcl launched terminal shows:

> Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1706706126.307448 but the latest data is at time 601.061000, when looking up transform from frame [odom] to frame [base_footprint])

Also When I try to move to bot using teleop, the laser_scan data also moves !!!

> RViz: Message Filter dropping message: frame ‘laser_frame’ at time 601.844 for reason ‘the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache’

My workspace : GitHub - [Vinothhk/2W_Diff_Bot](https://github.com/Vinothhk/2W_Diff_Bot)